# MariaDB and 1064 error

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I get the following error when I execute the code below:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 21: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   chech the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near @LINE_TERMINATION@

Here is the code that I use to create table:

```
CREATE TABLE SRDEF (
    RT  VARCHAR (3) BINARY NOT NULL,
    UI  CHAR (4) BINARY NOT NULL,
    STY_RL  VARCHAR (41) BINARY NOT NULL,
    STN_RTN VARCHAR (14) BINARY NOT NULL,
    EX  VARCHAR (185) BINARY
) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

And here is the code I use to populate table:

```
load data local infile 'SRDEF' into table SRDEF fields terminated by '|' 
ESCAPED BY '' lines terminated by @LINE_TERMINATION@
(@rt, @ui, @sty_rl, @stn_rtn, @ex)
SET RT = @rt,
UI = @ui,
STY_RL = @sty_rl,
STN_RTN = @stn_rtn,
EX = NULLIF(@ex,'');
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is `@LINE_TERMINATION@`???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what is `@LINE_TERMINATION@` here but change that to

```
lines terminated by '\n'
```

(OR)

```
lines terminated by '\r\n'
```

Else, out of my guess if `@LINE_TERMINATION@` is the string literal for line termination then specify it properly like

```
lines terminated by '@LINE_TERMINATION@'
```